# Running nfc-pcsc example triggers no events on linux

Tags: node.js, linux, nfc, pcsc

I cloned that repo [nfc-pcsc](https://github.com/pokusew/nfc-pcsc) and did the commands from the docs [running examples locally](https://github.com/pokusew/nfc-pcsc#running-examples-locally)
. Now when I execute `npm run example` I only see some startup messages.

```
> nfc-pcsc_examples@0.8.0 example /home/victorgorban2/Desktop/WEB/TEST/nfc-pcsc
> node -r @babel/register examples/read-write.js
```

It don't react to my NFC reader (ACR122U-A9). But on my Windows 10, everything just OK. I use Ubuntu 18.04

I just need this lib working. `nfc-list` command shows me that my nfc reader is recognized.

```
~/Desktop$ nfc-list
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
NFC device: ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface opened
```

My `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-libnfc.conf` file contents are:

```
blacklist nfc
blacklist pn533

blacklist pn533_usb
```

Maybe I'm missing some library?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this solution (from [node-pcsclite](https://github.com/pokusew/node-pcsclite#disabling-drivers-to-make-pcsclite-working-on-linux))
 is worked for me:

1. create file `/etc/modprobe.d/nfc-blacklist.conf`
2. write

`blacklist pn533_usb`

`blacklist pn533`

`blacklist nfc`

3. reboot
4. `systemctl enable pcscd`
5. `systemctl start pcscd`
6. Now you can run the examples

Answer (score 0):

I just joined and cant upvote but this helped me out, Thank You!

For anyone else with similar issues:
I also had to change my node version to 12.22.9
Check out nvm https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
nvm install 12.22.9 (or nvm install 12 should be fine)